# react mutilple items remove?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
   const craeteTodos = [
 {
   id: 1,
   text: "text1",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   text: "text2",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   text: "text3",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 4,
   text: "text4",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 5,
   text: "text5",
   done: true,
    },
  ];

  const removeId = [1,3,4] //action.id   array


  function todoReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

      case "REMOVE":
       return state.filter(
         (user, index, array) => user.id !== ???? //I don't know.
       );
     default:
       throw new Error("Error");
   }
 }
```

I click the createTodos item. Get each ID in an array. I want to delete it all at once. Attempted using filter but failed. I need your help.

//I want to delete ID1,3,4 by receiving the guest removeId as action array. What should I do?

Comment: `state.filter(user => removeId.indexOf(user.id)===-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `filter` and check the id of each item with `includes`.

```js
 const createTodos = [ 
 {
   id: 1,
   text: "text1",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   text: "text2",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   text: "text3",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 4,
   text: "text4",
   done: true,
 },
 {
   id: 5,
   text: "text5",
   done: true,
    },
  ];

  const removeId = [1,3,4] //action.id   array
  
  let filteredTodo = createTodos.filter((todo,index) => !removeId.includes(todo.id));

  console.log(filteredTodo);
```